# Is there a NuGet package for the Resharper Command Line Tools

Tags: nuget, resharper, command-line-tool

I downloaded the Resharper Command Line Tools from https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html, but I want to have the command line tools as a solution NuGet package.

Is there any package on the internet available? I found a link here https://chocolatey.org/packages/resharper-clt, but don't see this package in the 'Manage Nuget Packages for solution' dialog.

Any idea how I get this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, track this issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-415014.
We hope it will make in ReSharper 9.1 update.